# line bundles and spheres

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Suppose the tangent bundle of $S^{2n+1}$ has two trivial line subbundles. Are those real line bundles isomorphic? Does this imply that the orthogonal complements are isomorphic?

Comment: I don't understand, if you assume that the linebundles are trivial, then they're isomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{2n+1}\times \mathbb{R}$ and a fortiori isomorphic to each other. Two orthgonal complements for 2 different metrics for a subbundle of a given bundle will be isomorphic, and both will be isomorphic to the quotient bundle.

Comment: Should't the isomorphism between the line subbundles coming from an isomorphism of the tangent bundle to itself such that the quotient bundles are isomorphic?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You don't need a global isomorphism mapping the 1st line bundle to the second for them to be isomorphic. Nor to be isomorphic to the quotient.

Comment: Then I do not see how you get an isomorphism from $TS^{2n+1}/L_1$ to $TS^{2n+1}/L_2$ only by knowing that $L_1$ is abstract isomorphic to $L_2$.

Comment: This is not what I said. But I now understand that I misunderstood your questions. I thought it was two independant questions.

Comment: The answer to your second question is then no.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: The examples I know come from algebraic geometry, and bundles are much more "rigid" in that context, I will try to think of a counter example in the smooth case.

Comment: I don't know if the answer to the second is "no" for odd dim spheres, but is generally "no" for other manifolds.

Comment: @Ahr Why not an official answer?

Answer (score 2):

The group $\pi_n O(k)$ is in canonical bijection with vector bundles over $S^{n+1}$ of rank $k$ by what's known as the clutching construction. The effect of the inclusion homomorphism $\pi_k O(n) \to \pi_k O(n+1)$ in this language is to take the direct sum with the trivial bundle. Your question, then, asks what the kernel of $\pi_{2n} O(2n) \to \pi_{2n} O(2n+1)$ is.

Because our map $O(2n) \to O(2n+1)$ fits into a fiber sequence $$O(2n) \to O(2n+1) \to S^{2n},$$ the homomorphism of interest fits into a sequence $$\pi_{2n+1} O(2n) \to \pi_{2n+1} O(2n+1) \to \pi_{2n+1}(S^{2n}) \to \pi_{2n} O(2n) \to \pi_{2n} O(2n+1).$$ In particular, the kernel of this map is a quotient of $\Bbb Z/2 = \pi_{2n+1}(S^{2n})$ for $n>1$.

I claim that this cyclic group is $\Bbb Z/2$ for $n \geq 4$ and $n=2$, and is zero for $n=1,3$. That is to say, there are exactly two isomorphism classes of $(2n)$-plane bundles which embed as subbundles of $TS^{2n+1}$ for all $n$ except $1,3$.

I only know how to do this in a roundabout way: [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255455861) of Kervaire lists off $\pi_{k} O(k)$ and $\pi_k O(k+1)$ in a range $k \geq 8$, and in all cases the groups are such that any map $\pi_{2n} O(2n) \to \pi_{2n} O(2n+1)$ necessarily has kernel once $n \geq 4$.

All that is left is the low-dimensional cases.

For $n=0$ there is of course nothing to say.

For $n=1$ we have explicitly that $\pi_2 O(2) = 0$, so the kernel is automatically zero.

For $n=2$ we can exploit the exceptional isomorphisms to get $\pi_4 O(4) = (\Bbb Z/2)^2$ and $\pi_4 O(5) = \pi_4 \text{Sp}(2) = \pi_4 \text{Sp}(1) = \pi_4 S^3 = \Bbb Z/2$. So the kernel must be $\Bbb Z/2$.

For $n=3$ we have following the exceptional isomorphisms that $\pi_6 O(6) \cong \pi_6 U(4)$. This is in the stable range, where we necessarily have $\pi_6 U(4) \cong \pi_6 U = \pi_0 U = 0$.

Thus for almost all odd-dimensional spheres, there is exactly one non-trivial bundle whose sum is isomorphic to the tangent bundle.

Note that this is *not* computing the number of non-isomorphic $2n$-plane distributions in $TS^{2n+1}$. That is different.

Edited to fix my typo. Thank you to Jason DeVito for pointing it out.

Comment: +1 from me, very nice.  But I'm am confused by your last comment.  Where did $(n-1)$ come from?  The previously part of the answer is all about $2n$-plane distributions, right?